# Angular2: JQuery $.extend for Angular2/4

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

How can I use JQuery $.extend in Angular2 without using Jquery?

I try to use Object.assign but deep merging does not work.

An example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvGPOv

```
Object.assign( baseOptions, customOption);
```

Comment: I use lodash. You can install the merge function seperately: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.merge

Comment: You can always extract the function...

Comment: lodash merge works... thanks

Comment: did you find something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 2/4 does not provide any way to perform deep copy. It does not offer any opinion or implementation on deep copy of Javascript objects.

If your object does not contain functions or date objects then the below approach using pure Javascript way can work for you in most cases:

```
var clonedObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Once the object is cloned, you can assign additional properties to it.

Comment: Possibly merge function should be the most generic possible... In my case I have function also in the object